# How do I add gridView rows to a dataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

This is not working:

```
var originalFinalShowsTable = Session["finalShowsTable"] as DataTable;

DataTable finalShowsTable = new DataTable();

finalShowsTable = originalFinalShowsTable.Clone();

foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvShows.Rows)
{
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         if (((CheckBox) gvr.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
         {
               finalShowsTable.Rows.Add(gvr);
         }
     }
}
```

What it's doing is putting the text `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow"` into the first column of the data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
DataTable finalShowsTable = new DataTable();

    finalShowsTable = originalFinalShowsTable.Clone();

    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvShows.Rows)
    {
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
             if (((CheckBox) gvr.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
             {
                    DataRow dr= finalShowsTable.NewRow();
                     for (int i = 0; i < gvr.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
                     {
                         dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
                     }

                     finalShowsTable.Rows.Add(dr);
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Index out of range issue with the FOR loop. I cannot do gvr.Cells.Count because I'm not grabbing everything from the gridView. I'm only grabbing what's selected.

Comment: gvr cell count refers to the cells in current row.I think you are getting an index out of range exception since you have an extra column ( checkbox) in gridview.Try changing dr[i] = row.Cells[i+1].Text; compare the count of columns in datatable and grid

Comment: I actually had to do gvr.Cells.Count - 1, which did the trick. Thanks!